# One Invetory / Multiple Stores / Multiple Users / One Admin

Tags: admin, stores, marketplace, multiple

I need to build a project using Magento but I don't know if it can be built with such complexity.

This is the project's configuration:

- Only one Admin, which can do:

  - Manage all the inventory and can edit/exclude them all and its atributtes
  - Handle all orders, shipping, clients data
  - Manage all stores and users inside the software
  - Receive a comission-based value in every order received by the users
- Multiple Users, which can do:

  - Build his own store with custom sub-domain (eg. .store.com)
  - Change only the prices in all products in the inventory (with the minimum price set up by the admin).
  - Can see all orders from his store (can't edit or cancel)
  - Can make small changes in configuration (eg. main theme colors, logo, banner)
  - Receive his profit in his own account

Is there a extension/module that does it? Or multiple extensions that can help with all these needs? It is possible to build it using Magento?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. Seeing your requirements you no need to go with any special requirements since these are already present in Magento **User Roles**. You can have a single admin user who can manage all users and you can create users for each stores with restricted access. There are also a numerous user role extensions which does have additional functionalities extending the features of Magento User Roles.

Answer (score 0):

**Based on Your Requirement Magento Also Provide This Functionality**

> You Need to Just create **Admin User** And **Create User Role**

**Creating New User :-**

```
Admin Panel > Syastem > All User
```

**Creating User Role :-**

```
Admin panel > User Roles
```

> In the upper-right corner, click Add New Role button
>
> In the Role Information field, enter a descriptive Role Name.
>
> In the panel on the left, choose Role Resources.
>
> Set to Custom, then mark the checkbox of each website and view to
>   which the role is to have permission to access.
>
> Set to All if you want to mark all the checkbox